# Triple Laplace transform of a first order partial differential equation

Tags: laplace-transform

How to find $L_x L_y L_t \{(\frac{\partial}{\partial x}- \frac{\partial}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial}{\partial t}) f(x,y,t)\}$?
I have obtained $(s_1-s_2-s_3)F(s_1,s_2,s_3)+F(s_1,0,s_3)+F(0,s_2,s_3)-F(s_1,s_2,0)$ where $s_1,s_2,s_3$ are transform variables of $x,y,t$ respectively. whether I am correct or not I am sure?

Comment: Is the domain of $f = [0,\infty)^3$?

Comment: yes, you are right